# Print list in new line for each list in list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in list that look like this

```
[['a', 9] , ['b', 1] , ['c', 4] , . . ., ['z', 2]]
```

From here, I want to print out each list in the list line by line to look like this

```
['a',9]
['b',1]
. 
. 
['z',2]
```

I knew that I can just use loop to print it out like this:

```
for i in list:
   print(i)
```

but my question here is that, can it be done without using loop? Like just a one line that print this without interacting with loop. (I plan to use with some alert function so I want it to be in one large message containing all list , not multiple message with one list each)

I have tried this:

```
print(list, sep='\n')
```

but it doesn't separate into one line per list. I also tried this:

```
print('\n'.join(list))
```

and this error occured:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

which seem not to work with a list in list. Any idea?

Comment: For your last error, try `print('\n'.join(map(str, list)))`

Comment: You can post this as an answer

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to print this in some kind of alert function? Would you redirect the output stream used by print, or how are you planning to do this?

Comment: I created a function in which  it work like print() but instead of printing it out to terminal, it will send value inside this function to a chat. I avoiding loop here because I want it to be just one large message not multiple message @tobias_k

Comment: Okay, but then how will you transfer your knowledge of `print` to your function? E.g. does your function also support the `print(*lines)` syntax? `'\n'.join` should work, though. depending on how your chat works, you could also try `print(..., file=your_chat_stream)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, just add some list comprehension:

```
my_list = [['a', 9] , ['b', 1] , ['c', 4] , . . ., ['z', 2]]
print('\n'.join(str(el) for el in my_list ))
```

Comment: This one work well with my chat function but there are too many element in list it will show `..` at the last line.

Answer (score 7):

```
lst = [['a', 9] , ['b', 1] , ['c', 4]]

print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
['a', 9]
['b', 1]
['c', 4]
```